# libgtk2.0-common fails to build with Gdk-2.0.gir error, Type reference 'GdkPixbuf' not found

Tags: 10.10, programming, gtk, software-sources

I'm trying to build gtk, but it fails. Here's what I'm doing:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libgtk2.0-common
apt-get source libgtk2.0-common
cd gtk+2.0-2.22.0/
gedit gtk/gtktreeview.c &
#...editing a few files (or not, it's the same error)
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
```

The compilation runs for a while and then quits:

```
Gdk-2.0.gir: error: Type reference 'GdkPixbuf' not found
...
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you shouldn't use "sudo" for configure and make, it is only required for "make install", out of curiosity why are you trying to build gtk ? ?

Comment: The reason I'm trying to build gtk is to answer [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19958/how-can-i-change-the-timeout-duration-for-nautilus-find-the-filename-as-you-ty/19993#19993) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the package source you should compile using the package debian building rules instead of using the plain configure / make as you do from an original source.
To build using the package build rules, from the source directory, just run:

```
debuild
```

The manual building is probably failing because of a needed patch which is applied from the package building rules.