# How to disable the Nautilus searchbox?

Tags: nautilus

Is there any way by which I can disable the textbox?

Case study: say I have to locate a directory called "xyz". I type "xyz", and the browser will guide me to xyz directory, but I realise I also have to check in directory "abc", then I have to press escape, or backspace delete and search again for "abc". In Kubuntu, I simply have to type "abc" after a gap of say a second. That is very handy. I believe this can be achieved without a search box. Please tell me how.

Comment: I think you're asking two questions here: 1, how to disable the search box, and 2, how can I search without a searchbox. (Am I reading the question wrong?)

Comment: @james my bad.. How can i search without a searchbox would be more apt. so..how do i do that ?

Comment: nothing worked. So i just installed dolphin the default kubuntu browser to ubuntu. and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

The timeout does exists. By default 5 seconds after you type anything, the search box will vanish.

Unfortunately, as with too many Gnome variables, this timeout is hard-coded into Nautilus so there's no easy way to fix this. The only way I know of is [downloading the source, editing it and recompiling Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19958/how-can-i-change-the-timeout-duration-for-nautilus-find-the-filename-as-you-ty/19993#19993).

Those instructions aren't hard to follow and should work.

Answer (score 0):

To default Breadcrumbs view in Nautilus open `gconf-editor`, go to *apps -> nautilus -> preferences* and untick **always_use_location_entry**:

[image]

Comment: I know this does not exactly answer your question, but at least it disables the default textbox view.

Comment: followed this.. but nautilus still shows the textbox..

Comment: I tested this for 10.04 and 10.10: when ticked -> textbox, when unticked -> breadcrumb view.