# Prevent files from losing focus in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, focus

One of my pet peeves in Ubuntu:

I open up a folder with ~50 files in it. I start typing in the file name, and it matches something. I notice that the file I want is *right beside it*. I press the right arrow... nothing happens. I press it again, thinking it was a mis-press... still nothing happens. Nothing happens until I press Escape, and *then* select the file -- because the incremental search box has grabbed the focus.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: And why is this an issue, it looks like it was meant to be that way, you type something then the searchbox appears and you press enter to open the file/folder or use the **mouse**  to select the item next to it.

Comment: That and that nothing happens simply because you are using the search box, pressing left or right moves the cursor in it, as it should and not the item selection.

Comment: @Uri: You're supposed to *use the mouse*? In *Linux*? I hope you're not being serious...

Comment: uhmm yes? as with any other modern non-touchscreen UI...you move the mouse cursor around, selecting stuff, that's why there's one to start with.

Comment: @Uri: Long story short, let's just say that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: As mentioned here:http://askubuntu.com/questions/33918/how-to-disable-the-nautilus-searchbox the search feature is hardcoded into it and you would need to compile Nautilus by yourself to modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: press down arrow of keyboard instead  of right

Answer (score 1):

Hit tab to restore focus to the file list. Then you should be able to navigate with the arrow keys.

Comment: hm, this does the same as 'escape', so probably doesn't help!

Comment: There's no way for nautilus to tell whether you're trying to navigate the file list, or move the cursor within the search box. So, I guess you'll have to do the extra keypress.