# How to automatically expand location with File Open dialog?

Tags: gtk, filemanager, xubuntu, dialog

## Background

By default, the "File Open" dialog resembles:

[image: Example Open Dialog]

## Problem

More often than not, my first interaction with this dialog is to click the pencil icon to reveal the path. I then paste the path from my terminal window (`pwd`), which is often many times faster than clicking around within the open dialog to get to the same path.

## Question

How do you make the location input field in the "File Open" dialog always be displayed, regardless of the application (e.g., GIMP, Inkscape, and other applications)?

## Related

- [How do I set the default sort order in open file dialog to "Name"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83552/how-do-i-set-the-default-sort-order-in-open-file-dialog-to-name?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Display path once

From the breadcrumb view in both Nautilus (top), and Thunar (bottom) we can temporarily disable breadcrumb view by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>:

[image]
[image]

The path will aready be selected ready for copy & paste.

---

### Disable Nautilus breadcrumbs

We can set the default behaviour for Nautilus using **dconf-editor** when [dconf-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools] are installed. Browse to `org.gnome.nautilus.preferences` and tick **always-use-location-entry** to display the path rather than the breadcrumbs view:

[image]

Alternatively you can simply execute this command in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry true
```

After that Nautilus will display the current location in a path view:

[image]

The file selector will then also have the additional line to add the path which also will be shown on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> or clicking the pencil (see above):

[image]

Untick the option to switch back to breadcrumb view.

---

For older Ubuntu releases using **gconf-editor** browse to *apps -> nautilus -> preferences* and untick **always_use_location_entry** ([see this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33918/how-to-disable-the-nautilus-searchbox)).

---

To my knowledge we can't change the default behaviour in Thunar.