# My /home size is 350GB and '/' size is 15GB. But filling /home with data is filling '/' also as /home is under '/'. What do i do?

Tags: root, home-directory

My `/home` size is 350 GB and `/` size is 15 GB. But filling `/home` with data is filling `/` also as `/home` is under `/`.

Gparted shows that I've used up 58.90 GB of the 350 GB but that's not true.

Here is the screenshot of GParted:
[image]

Here is the screenshot of 'properties' of '/':
[image]

Here is the screenshot of 'properties' of /home folder:
[image]

Comment: Space in /home maybe mounted on / (all file systems are), however they don't use space on your / partition.  My own system sits on a 36gb / partition, my /home is also 30gb, but if I look at what is mounted on my / partition, it's >20TB of file-systems (ie. mostly NFS shares; and my network shares couldn't possibly fit on my 36gb / partition if they used disk space there). I think you're confused, but sorry I don't see where.

Comment: The / folder is counting the contents of /home also. So the problem is i get an error  message saying the file root system is full and I am unable to install new app or download new data. After moving some data from downloads folder i have freed up some space though but i guess that's not the real solution.

Comment: Your / partition will get filled by the addition of added software, why I use 36gb (which I often wish was bigger), or you don't do general housecleaning (ie. `sudo apt autoremove; sudo apt autoclean`) .. 15gb means you'll can't add loads of software packages, esp. snaps ; the recommended size is 25gb (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) so you need to be lean with additional software you add (esp. come *release-upgrade* time as you need space to download before upgrade.. why 25gb is recommended minimum)

Comment: I have performed autoremove and autoclean but it has freed only 1 GB

Comment: How can i increase the / space?

Comment: @user535733 it is mounted because Gparted is showing option to unmount when i right-click on the /home tab

Comment: @user535733 Why is the /home shown as using 58.9 GB when in actual it has only 5GB data?
See screenshots above

Comment: what is the output of `du -sh /home` (this might take a while)?

Comment: Output of  du -sh /home:  54G /home

Comment: So the output of the file manager is just wrong here and everything is fine. Use something like `baobab` (Disk usage analyzer) to see where the 54G sits.

Comment: That's simply not true. I literally know all the files in the home folder. They add upto only around 5 gb

Comment: it seems you don't know...

Comment: @pLumo I checked using baobab and the Disk Usage Analyzer windows popped up.It shows a folder named '.bitcoin' consuming 49.3GB space. But i don't have any such folder

Comment: You have that directory, you just don't see it. Files and directories beginning with `.` are hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is in order. Your `/home` is on a separate partition and does not fill space on `/`. Your home has 54G of data.

The problem here is, that Nautilus does not count hidden files even if you show them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>.
I would consider this a bug, it was already [asked before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802077/how-do-i-get-a-folder-size-in-nautilus-to-include-hidden-files-dotfiles).

You need to go to Preferences and check "Show hidden files"

[image: Show hidden files]

Then your directory size in the preferences will be correct.

---

Regarding your comment: If you have a directory `.bitcoin` in your home folder that you don't know, check for some unwanted malware processes and bitcoin mining software. If your computer got compromised: [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) (hint: reinstall your system)

Comment: My cousin had used my computer for a few days and it seems he has something to do with the bitcoin files. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: How do i increase space of the '/' folder. Can i do it without using a live cd because i don't have one?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/237453/631600